# ASP.NET User Control (ascx) inside php File

Tags: php, html, asp.net, iis-7

We have a nice looking dynamic website developed in php. server is IIS7.

Also I have a asp.net user control[ascx], which is a special utility calendar with a nice UI and lot of DB interactions.

Can I put this asp.net user control inside one of the php file?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do this in a normal way. You can do this if you use an Iframe and call an asp.net page where your user control exists in your php website.